# Searching Database Entity With Search Opeands(Like, Greater than, Less than, Between, ...)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, architecture, ado.net-entity-data-model

I use criteria classes for search database in ado.net. For example, for searcing Users in db, I use UserSearchCriteria class to search with operands like "like", "between", "greater than", "less than"... For example search Username contains, DisableCount greater than and Id exact match so on.

Currently Search function call :

```
   var users = userManager.Search(new UserSearchCriteria() { Id = new 
   Dictionary<int,OperandTypeEnum>(1,OperandTypeEnum.ExactMatch),
   Username = new Dictionary<string, OperandTypeEnum>("John Doe",OperandTypeEnum.Like),
   DisableCount = new Dictionary<int, OperandTypeEnum>(5,OperandTypeEnum.GreaterThan)});
```

The question is that, is there a better option to search with operands? Because simplified calling search function would be better.

```
public enum OperandTypeEnum
{
    ExactMatch=0, // default
    Like,
    GreaterThan,
    LessThan,
    Between
}

public class UserSearchCriteria
{
    public Dictionary<int?,OperandTypeEnum>  Id { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, OperandTypeEnum> Username { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, OperandTypeEnum> DisableCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If this Id is the primary key of that table then it would be enough for searching exclude other parameters. For other condition like getting by username with greater than disable count you can add them with method overloading. If you are not satisfied with this answer i think i don't get your question clearly, then would you please elaborate more than this ?

Comment: Id is an example property actually. Usually i am doing search with non primary key fields. But only way seems method overloading to me, too.